# How to get fabric commands to update output in place?

Tags: python, fabric, pipenv

Pipenv updates the commandline output in place. Fabric 1.14.0 sees every update as a new line. This results in lot of superfluous ouput.

I've read the documentation of the run operation. Tried setting capture_buffer_size to 100. Didn't make a difference.

```
def install_packages():
    "Install packages on the remote host."""
    with cd('/data/repo/'):
        run("pipenv install", capture_buffer_size=100)
```

Actual results:

> [server] run: pipenv install
>   [server] out: Creating a virtualenv for this project…
>   [server] out: Pipfile: /data/repo/Pipfile
>   [server] out: Using /usr/bin/python3.5 (3.5.2) to create virtualenv…
>   [server] out:
>   [server] out: ⠋ Creating virtual environment...
>   [server] out: ⠙ Creating virtual environment...
>   [server] out: ⠹ Creating virtual environment...
>   [server] out: ⠸ Creating virtual environment...
>
> ......
>
> [server] out: ✔ Successfully created virtual environment!

Expected results:

> [server] run: pipenv install
>   [server] out: Creating a virtualenv for this project…
>   [server] out: Pipfile: /data/repo/Pipfile
>   [server] out: Using /usr/bin/python3.5 (3.5.2) to create virtualenv…
>   [server] out:
>   [server] out: ⠋ Creating virtual environment...
>   [server] out: ✔ Successfully created virtual environment!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `run("pipenv install")` instruction in a `with hide('output')` context manager. Remove the `capture_buffer_size` kwarg.

More information about tuning your output can be found [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/usage/output_controls.html)